# Firefinder alternative

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug, firefox6

Since upgrading to Firefox 6, one of my favourite extensions for firebug no longer works.  Does anyone know of an alternative to firefinder?

I'm looking for a tool to highlight DOM elements from CSS/XPATH selectors. Preferrably connected to firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefinder has been updated, see http://robertnyman.com/2011/09/05/firefinder-and-inline-code-finder-updated-to-work-with-the-latest-firebug-versions/.

Answer (score 1):

If a Firefox addon is not compatible to your version, you can try to modify the *.xpi file like described here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_an_add-on_to_change_its_compatibility.

Comment: Firefinder is compatible with Firefox 6. It does not seem to be compatible with Firebug 1.8.